# How to fetch and display image in React, saved in Mongodb as Cloudinary URL

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, cloudinary

I just started using Cloudinary to upload picture in an application am working on. It is stored in MongoDB database as url link. I have succeeded with the upload. My database looks like this after saving:

```
id:5f90315331dc1727bc869afe
userEmail:"fletcher@gmail.com"
image:"https://res.cloudinary.com/myapp/image/upload/v1603285331/ifyo38crk..."
imageId:"ifyo38crkdniixeimme9"
__v:0
```

My get() endpoint looks like this :

```
app.get("/getAvatar/:email", (req, res) => {
  userEmail= req.params.email;
  Image.find({userEmail:userEmail},(err, images)=> {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500);
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(images);
    }
  });
});
```

and my  React front-end :

```
class AllImages extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const{user}=this.props.auth
        const email = user.email
        this.props.getAvatar(email)
    }
    render() {
        return this.props.resumeData.map(image=>{
            return(
                <div className="image-card-container">
                    <div key={image.id} className='image-card'>
                        <h4>{image.userEmail}</h4>
                        <img
                        className='main-image'
                        src={image.image}
                        alt='profile image'
                        />

                    </div>


                </div>
            )
```

Redux action :

```
 export const getAvatar=(email)=>dispatch=>{
          
          dispatch(AvatarLoading());
          axios.post('/getAvatar/'+ email )
          .then(res=>
    dispatch({ 
      type:     GET_RESUME_AVATAR,
    payload: res.data
    
    })
    
    )
    history.push('/');
    };
```

On componentMount() i get the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

something is definitely wrong with my code. This is my first time of working with Cloudinary, I will appreciate if anyone can help out!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `null` check inside `render()`

```
class AllImages extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const{user}=this.props.auth
        const email = user.email
        this.props.getAvatar(email)
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
            {this.props.resumeData && this.props.resumeData.map(image=>{
              return(
                <div className="image-card-container">
                    <div key={image.id} className='image-card'>
                        <h4>{image.userEmail}</h4>
                        <img
                        className='main-image'
                        src={image.image}
                        alt='profile image'
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
              )}
           </div>
        )
    }
```

The `render` will get executed before `componentDidMount` and re-rendered on prop change.

Comment: thanks for your response. this is what i got after making use of your suggestion : "Error: AllImages(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Comment: I got the same Error!

Comment: Try to print the resume data